# Why is "return" needed before randomHull() in the else statement?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, recursion, return

The goal of this function is to return a value between 3 and 6. I know there is an easier way to do this, but am just trying to understand how/why this option works.

The below function works, but only if you use return in the else statement. If you do not use "return randomHull()" and instead put just "randomHull()" it will return undefined if the first attempt is not within the range.

My initial understanding was that return was not needed as the value would only be stored if the if statement was true, otherwise it would just run randomHull() again until it passed through the if statement and returned a value within the range.

Why is "return" needed before randomHull() in the else statement?

```
const randomHull = () => {
     let alienHull = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
     if (alienHull >= 3) {
        return alienHull;
     } else {
        return randomHull();
     }

}

console.log(randomHull());
```

Comment: Bottom line.  Inside a normal function, or in an arrow function that uses `{}` around the function expression(s), without a return statement a method will not return anything.  Arrow functions only return implicitly if they do not wrap their expression with `{}`.  And normal functions never implicitly return expression results

Comment: Also just as a side note; the usage of recursion in this case is unnecessary.  A simple while loop on the conditional being false to get another value would perform the same logic, without making extra calls.  `while (alienHull < 3) alienHull = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);`  and done

Answer (score 1):

Say it finds a match on the second attempt.

The first attempt hits the else branch, then calls the `randomHull` function.

The return value from that is passed back to the calling function (the first call to `randomHull`). Then nothing would be done with it (it isn't returned because you took `return` out, it isn't stored in a variable because you don't do that either, etc).

The first call to `randomHull` contains. It hits the `}` to end the else block. Then it hits the `}` to end the function. Since it reached the end of the function without a `return` statement, it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This a recursive function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

It works because it calls itself again until it meets the condition in the if. Every execution will be a step closer to `>= 3` and eventually hit the case in the if.